# Quais as vantagens de usar um modelo Snowflake, Star, sob um modelo relacional para B.I?

Tags: modelo-relacional, business-intelligence

Olá,

Hoje em dia, vejo muitas ferramentas de B.I no mercado fazendo propaganda de que suas ferramentas são "plug'n play", conectam com bases relacionais, excels e "instantaneamente geram sistemas de B.I".

Isso me gerou uma certa duvida, pois eu já estagiei na área de B.I e lembro que sempre usávamos um misto do Snowflake Schema e Star Schema, de maneira alguma recorríamos ao relacional. Porém nunca foi me explicado muito bem o porque disso.

O que me vem a cabeça do porque seria:

**- Poder fazer drill ups e drill downs devido a estrutura do Snowflake Schema**

**- Poder quebrar o valor por qualquer parte(dimensões), o que só poderia ser possível no relacional por meio de "tabelões" nas tabelas de valores**

**- Ter uma parcela de informação só até certo nível, sem granularidade exagerada (Previne que, por exemplo, o usuário tente executar uma query ou gráfico em algo gigante e muito granular).** 
.

Desvantagens:

**-Ter que transformar os dados do mundo relacional para o modelo dimensional**

Existe outras vantagens/desvantagens que eu não esteja lembrando?
Vocês acham que para uma empresa de médio a grande porte realmente seria melhor adotar um modelo dimensional ao invés do modelo relacional?

Obrigado!!

Answer (score -2):

O modelo Dimensional foi projetado para ler e trabalhar com dados analíticos, com o menor numero de joins no percurso para buscar uma informação. As tabelas de dimensão possuem valores únicos, e geralmente são largas e com bem menos linhas que as tabelas de Fato. O modelo Snowflake é desaconselhado. Uma modelagem bem feita no StarShema facilita muito a criação das medidas para atender os KPIs do negócio. O modelo dimensional necessita ser desnomarlizado, justamente o contrário de um modelo ER (altamente normalizado). Um modelo dimensional bem construído, possibilita a leitura de tabelas gigantescas de forma muita rápida. As tabelas de dimensão funcionam como filtros diretos sobre a tabela de fatos, e no modelo StarShema, basta apenas um único join entre a Fato e cada tabela Dimensão.